# Authorization header is not setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have one method for login as per below :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    string url = "API_URL";

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, loginModel);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonData = JObject.Parse(result);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + jsonData["accessToken"]);

        return RedirectToAction("PostLogin");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "These credentials does not work. Hmm..");
    }

    return View(loginModel);
}
```

Now in this if user successfully login then I am getting token and also I am setting that in header. Now after that I am redirecting user to PostLogin method.

But in that method I am not able to access that token. Below is code for that.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PostLogin()
{
    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("accessToken"); // Here I can't see token. and getting value as per below.

    return View();
}
```

Even I am getting this error as per below :

`InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultAuthenticateScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).`

Comment: Where is `client` variable defined?

Comment: @AleksaRistic at top of the controller :  public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured a default authentication scheme in your `Startup` class, something like `services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

Comment: @MartinCostello I have made changes like this : public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @SamiIn: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183105/setting-new-access-token-in-current-httpcontext-session

Answer (score 1):

You have commented that at start of controller you have `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` which is new instance of `HttpClient`

So in your function you are setting that objects authorization using this line: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + jsonData["accessToken"]);`.

After that you are getting users authorization from current `HttpContext` which is sent each time user visits some link and it does not have anything with your `client` object you just set authorization to.

Since you are redirecting you must change current `HttpContext` authorization header since it will be carried to redirected request. Do it by changing `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`. Problem is that it will only last that request so you need to give token back to client so he sends it in header each time he makes request.

Comment: I understand what you want to say..but I am confused where I need to use this HttpContext in my login method OR in post login method